# How to connect to Bitbucket via Python?

Tags: python, bitbucket

I am facing difficulties connecting to the Bitbucket repo from python. I have come across few python modules which let us connect to the Bitbucket repository from python. I have tried 'Bitbucket-python' which enables me to connect to the Bitbucket repo but still i am not able to list out the repositories by using the same module.

Can you please suggest me any python module which i can use for the purpose?

I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bikram

Comment: You can use the Bit-bucket REST API along python to get the list of repositories.
Bitbucket Cloud: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stashy`](https://stashy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module.

For example:

```
import stashy

bitbucket = stashy.connect("host", "username", "password")
projects = bitbucket.projects.list()
repos = bitbucket.repos.list()

for project in projects:
    for repo in bitbucket.projects["%s" % (project["key"])].repos.list():
        print(repo["name"])
        print(repo["project"]['key'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using python's requests module and this url https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-group-repositories as reference

To see if you have a connection maybe do something like this:
The {workspace} is your workspaceid and the api key I generated under the security tab in you bitbucket account. Good luck!

```py
import requests
import json


headers = {
    '{API key}': '{API secret}'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

#Get repo list

url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}"
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response) # 200 reponse means there is a connection

#or if you have repos try this to print them

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```