# How to access bitbucket from python?

Tags: bitbucket

I googled and found 2 results, but none works...

1. https://pypi.org/project/bitbucket-python/, i failed in login.. I tried APP password and bitbucket account password, all failed with `bitbucket.exceptions.NotAuthenticatedError: Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method.`
2. https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/bitbucket.html, but I have no idea where to found the API it mentioned...

Any suggestion?

Comment: Duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613263/how-to-connect-to-bitbucket-via-python ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [#2](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/bitbucket.html), if you navigate to the [main page](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html) you'll notice;

```
pip install atlassian-python-api
```

There are also badges at the top of that page that will take you to [that package on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/).

I'm surprised to see the unofficial package has recent updates, since the official packages were released.

Comment: Ah.. it reminds me I tried the official package 2 months ago and frustrated in login after 2 hours tried, kind of issues from bitbucket-python..

Comment: I just tried atlassian-python-api and it seems works fine.. thanks